# Play WebView video from my app with other app's music

Tags: javascript, android, webview, youtube, android-music-player

I am using following code its working fine to play Youtube video with autoplay and mute functionality, but when its playing video then my music app stopped working..
Only one is working at a time...

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
    String  videoURL = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/R52bof3tvZs";

    String vid = "<html><body style=\"margin: 0; padding: 0\"><iframe  width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src=\""+videoURL+"\" type=\"text/html\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe><body><html>";

    WebChromeClient mWebChromeClient = new WebChromeClient(){
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        }
    };

    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()");
        }
    });
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setInitialScale(1);
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17) {
        Log.i("GPSNETWORK", "<17");
    } else {
        Log.i("GPSNETWORK", Build.VERSION.SDK_INT+">=17");
        mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    }

    String myUrl = "&lt;html&gt;&lt;body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'&gt;\n" +
            "        &lt;script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script type='text/javascript'&gt;\n" +
            "                var player;\n" +
            "        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()\n" +
            "        {player=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}\n" +
            "        function onPlayerReady(event){player.mute();player.setVolume(0);player.playVideo();}\n" +
            "        &lt;/script&gt;\n" +
            "        &lt;iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='1280' height='720'\n" +
            "        src="+videoURL+"?enablejsapi=1&amp;rel=0&amp;playsinline=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;controls=0&amp;modestbranding=1' frameborder='0'&gt;\n" +
            "        &lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;";
    mWebView.loadData(""+Html.fromHtml(myUrl), "text/html", "UTF-8");`
```

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, I fixed it with flag making true when player state is ready, 
and placing(checking) that flag where I was performing pause of player, It lets run both simultaneously

```
String myUrl = "&lt;html&gt;&lt;body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'&gt;\n" +
            "        &lt;script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;&lt;script type='text/javascript'&gt;\n" +
            "                var player;\n" +
            "        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()\n" +
            "        {player=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady, onStateChange: onPlayerStateChange}})}\n" +
            "        var done = false;\n" +
            "        function onPlayerReady(event){player.mute();player.setVolume(0);player.playVideo();done =
```

> \""+bool(true)+"\"

;}\n";

```
private boolean bool(boolean b)
{
    you_tube_started = b;
    Log.e(TAG, "you_tube_started  "+you_tube_started);
    return b;
}
```

Here used like this

```
if (mMediaPlayer != null && isPrepared) {
                    if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS : Nothing  you_tube_started  "+you_tube_started);
                        if(!you_tube_started)
                            pausePlayer();
                        pausedDueToAudioFocusLoss = true;
                        /*mMediaPlayer.stop();
                        mMediaPlayer.reset();*/
                    }

                }
```